# C# upcasting of one type in a two-type generic doesn't work

Tags: c#, generics, collections, casting, covariance

I prepared a sample application of a problem I have in a big WPF application.

The issue I have is with upcasting the second type of the TreeColumn instance `obsTreeColumn` to a `Collection`.
As you can see when I do this with just one type the upcast works fine.
The method `DoSomethingWithColumn` needs to be able to work with any type of collection as the second generic type of the parameter `collection`.

```
public class TreeColumn<T, TValue>  where TValue : Collection<T> {
    // A lot happens in here...
}

public class Data {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    // And much more...
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var expander = new TreeExpander<Data>();
        var obsTreeColumn = new TreeColumn<Data, ObservableCollection<Data>>();
        var colTreeColumn = new TreeColumn<Data, Collection<Data>>();

        var obsCollection = new ObservableCollection<Data>();
        var colCollection = new Collection<Data>();

        expander.DoSomethingWithColumn(obsTreeColumn);
        expander.DoSomethingWithColumn(colTreeColumn);
        expander.DoSomethingWithCollection(obsCollection);
        expander.DoSomethingWithCollection(colCollection);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class TreeExpander<T> where T : class {

    private int _rowCounter;

    public void DoSomethingWithColumn(object column) {

        // WHY ISN'T THIS CAST WORKING WITH A TreeColumn<T, ObservableCollection<T>>????
        var cast2 = column as TreeColumn<T, Collection<T>>;
        WriteLine("Cast to 'TreeColumn<T, Collection<T>>': ");
        WasCastSuccess(cast2);

        WriteLine("");
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithCollection(object collection) {

        var cast2 = collection as Collection<T>;
        WriteLine("Cast to 'Collection<T>': ");
        WasCastSuccess(cast2);

        WriteLine("");
    }

    private void WasCastSuccess(object o) {
        WriteLine(o != null ? "PERFECT!" : "Cast didn't work :(");
    }

    private void WriteLine(string msg) {
        _rowCounter++;
        Console.WriteLine(_rowCounter.ToString("00")+": "+msg);
    }
}
```

The console output is:

```
01: Cast to 'TreeColumn<T, Collection<T>>':
02: Cast didn't work :(
03:
04: Cast to 'TreeColumn<T, Collection<T>>':
05: PERFECT!
06:
07: Cast to 'Collection<T>':
08: PERFECT!
09:
10: Cast to 'Collection<T>':
11: PERFECT!
12:
```

I need to come up with something so line 2 of the output reads PERFECT!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) keyword to specify that the type parameter is covariant.

```
public interface ITreeColumn<T, out TValue> where TValue : Collection<T>
{
    // A lot declared in here..
}

public class TreeColumn<T, TValue> : ITreeColumn<T, TValue> where TValue : Collection<T>
{
    // A lot happens in here..
}
```

Comment: I didn't except a so simple solution,awesome! I also had to change the cast to `var cast2 = column as ITreeColumn<T, Collection<T>>;`

Comment: Yes, i fogot about changing to interface